# MYSQL database columns that have space in its name

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL database with columns that have space in their name like "first name" and want to rename to "first_name" but couldn't and I want help on it.

Comment: -1 For not doing any research or showing what you tried (if you really tried at all). [Click here before you post your next question.](http://s.tk/onhold)

Answer (score 0):

If you have column having space in it in your database then just escape it by backticks ` when you select it .

like that

```
 SELECT `first name` From your table
```

to rename your column . you need to alter your table like that

```
  Alter table table_name CHANGE `first name` `first_name` VARCHAR(25)
```

**Reference:** [Changing column name in mysql table](http://www.phponwebsites.com/2013/12/mysql-change-column-name.html)